# Swift 6: Actor-isolated instance method can not be referenced from a non-isolated context

Tags: swift, macos, actor

I need to setup a dictionary in an Actor. When I try the code the below I get a Actor-isolated instance method can not be referenced from a non-isolated context.

```
actor SimpleActor
{
    var myDict: [Int: String] = [:]
    
    init()
    {
        myDict = loadDict()
    }
    
    func loadDict() -> [Int: String]
    {
        var d: [Int: String] = [:]
        for i in 1...10
        {
            d[i] = "\(i)"
        }
        return d
    }

}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Get rid of `loadDict` and do: `myDict = (1...10).reduce(into: [:], { $0[$1] = "\($1)" })`.

Comment: I think my question was more how do you call the function as my real world application is more involved?